# AWS Flow log shows ACCEPTED on one ENI, REJECTED on other ENI

Tags: amazon-web-services

I am troubleshooting connectivity problem on my application server. Traffic is routed from ELB to app server. I look into flow log of ELB ENI and see that communication works:

`2 123456789 eni-aaa 172.17.30.184 172.17.31.148 58134 8080 6 3 180 1626806084 1626806143 ACCEPT OK`

App server ENI shows REJECTED
`2 123456789 eni-bbb 172.17.30.184 172.17.31.148 58134 8080 6 3 180 1626806081 1626806093 REJECT OK`

What is the logic behind ACCEPTED?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Flow log ACCEPT and REJECT often come from security groups and NACLs issues. In this case, it seems security group of `eni-aaa` accepts traffic, but security group of `eni-bbb` does not.

[flow log doc](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/vpc/latest/userguide/flow-logs-records-examples.html#flow-log-example-accepted-rejected)

[eni doc](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/using-eni.html)

Comment: According to my understanding, if traffic is blocked, flow log should show that request is REJECTED in both case, 'eni-aaa' and 'eni-bbb'. How is it possible that outgoing is ACCEPTED (eni-aaa) and incomming is REJECTED (eni-bbb)
BTW. I reviewed ACL and SGs on eni-bbb side and everything loooks fine.

Comment: I'm afraid Flow logs can detect for each eni in/out separately regardless traffic is blocked or not. I guess your case is similar to the case in this [doc](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticloadbalancing/latest/network/load-balancer-monitoring.html). Please refer the part "If the security group of the instance doesn't allow..."